# ffmpeg build for android.error:./obj/local/arm64-v8a/libavcodec.so: error adding symbols: File in wrong format

Tags: android, ffmpeg

Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := avcodec
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libavcodec.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := avdevice
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libavdevice.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)


include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := avfilter
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libavfilter.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := avformat
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libavformat.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := avutil
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libavutil.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := swresample
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libswresample.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := swscale
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libswscale.so
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)


include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := ffmpeg_main
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := com_piyingke_app_common_ffmpeg_FFmpegUtil.c \
                   com_piyingke_app_common_ffmpeg_FFmpegUtil.h
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/include
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog -lz
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := avcodec avdevice avfilter avformat avutil  swresample swscale
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

And i get an error :

> ./obj/local/arm64-v8a/libavcodec.so: error adding symbols: File in wrong format
>
> clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
>
> make: *** [obj/local/arm64-v8a/libffmpeg_main.so] Error 1

What should i do?Who can help me.

Comment: how did you build shared libraries such as libavcodec.so ? For which CPU architecture have you compiled them? It occurs to me that you have not proper so files.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a Application.mk?

You should only run builds for prebuilt files.

Like This :

```
APP_ABI:=armeabi-v7a
```